# What are the potential side effects of overwriting __eq__ and __hash__ in the Django framework?

Tags: python, django

I am working with collections of instances of a model defined in my Django application and it would be advantageous if I could use the `set` class to process these collections. In order for set to compare these model instances correctly, I need to override the `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods in these models so they no longer use the built in model Ids.

For example, if I had a "widget" model with "expiry" and "quantity" fields, I need model instances to be considered equal in sets when they have the same "expiry" and "quantity" even if they have different ids.

I've overridden these methods to compare model instances based on a subset of their fields. I am no longer using the model pks/ids to check for equivalence:

```
class Widget(model):

    expiry = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

...


    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Widget):
            return False
        else:
            return (
                self.expiry == other.expiry and
                self.quantity == other.quantity)

    def __hash__(self):

        widget_hash = hash(
            hash(self.expiry) ^
            hash(self.quantity))

        return widget_hash

...
```

My code using the `set` class to process the collections is working as needed, however I am concerned as to what side effects these changes may have in the Django framework.

- Does Django rely on the base implementation of `__eq__` and `__hash__`? Will there be side effects in the Django framework because I have changed the implementation of `__eq__` and `__hash__` to no longer use unique Ids?
- Alternatively, is there a way to override `set` the set class or inject custom methods for checking equivalence when using methods like `difference`?

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why do you need *"model instances to be considered equal in sets when they have the same "expiry" and "quantity" even if they have different ids."*? I am fairly certain there is a better approach to the underlying issue.

Comment: In my situation these models are both representing the same real world object, and yes there are red flags here with that architecture. Assuming we have a legitimate reason to override __eq__ and __hash__, what side effects could there be in the Django framework?

Comment: If they represent the same real world object, shouldn't you try to avoid them as duplicates in the database in the first place. Maybe add a custom PK column, a natural key that you fill using the two other fields.

Comment: I think in a lot of cases you would be correct, however my real world problem is a little more complicated than the example I've provided here and unfortunately it's not possible to change the primary key for these models. When these instances are in collections I need them to be considered equal based on a subset of their fields. Overriding the `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods make that possible and does not conflict with our current code base.

Comment: Possibly :) I would not feel well doing so. Maybe you can come up with more taylor made data structure other then `set` where you can use some custom method of your model instead of dunders.